# Named Queries not working org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'DATETIME'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I have one named query and in that query there is a SQL server method to convert the date.

```
@NamedQuery(query="SELECT a FROM Employee a WHERE a.id = :id AND (a.dob > CONVERT(DATETIME, :dob, 102)")
```

During migrating this to Hibernate 6,getting the following error.

```
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'DATETIME'
```

Comment: You have to remember that you are writing JPQL not SQL.

Comment: How to convert it . Any fix. @M.Deinum

Comment: Use JPQL or use SQL but not a combination of both, I also wonder why the call to the convert method in the first place? Ifyou are already passing in a date type why would it needed to be converted?

Comment: Need to use convert method as i need the date in a specific format

Comment: Why? What is the type of the `dob` field in your entity? JPA will do the conversion, that is the whole point of using things like JPA.

Comment: This is Date type in my entity.

Comment: Then why not let JPA do the conversion, just write `a.dob < :dob`, JPA should do the proper conversion and that shouldn't be something you should need to do. With the proper dialect and type being set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255872/discussion-between-debendra-dhinda-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am getting 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument [2003-05-30 09:36:00] of type [java.lang.String] did not match parameter type [java.util.Date (n/a)]`
 error. And please let me know the solution without converting the string to date.

Comment: The solution is to convert it to a date, that way JPA will do the lifting for you. Else write a SQL query and not a JPQL/SQL mixture. But the easiest is to convert it to a `Date`.